# dragulaModel of ng2-dragula is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-services, dragula

I am using [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) for my project andd it worked well for me.but now I want to pass data while dropping an element in the bag.

I searched on internet and found `dragulaModel` but when I am trying to use it it my code its not working.
I have done the following in my template:

```
<li *ngFor="#comp of record.components | search:searchComp:true" [dragula]='"row-bag"' [dragulaModel]='record.components'>
    <p class="text-center h6" style="font-size:8px;color:blue;font-weight:bold;"> {{comp.name }}</p>                                
</li>
```

and in my component :

```
 dragulaService.dropModel.subscribe((value:any[]) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.dragulaService.onDropModel(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.removeModel.subscribe((value:any[]) => {
        console.log(value);
        this.dragulaService.onRemoveModel(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.drag.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
        //console.log(`drag: ${value[0]}`);
        this.onDrag(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.drop.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
        //console.log(`drop: ${value[0]}`);
        this.onDrop(value.slice(1));           
    });
    dragulaService.over.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
        //console.log(`over: ${value[0]}`);
        this.onOver(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.out.subscribe((value: any[]) => {
        //console.log(`out: ${value[0]}`);
        this.onOut(value.slice(1));
    });
    dragulaService.setOptions('row-bag', {
        copy: true
    });
```

but I am getting this error:

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error message showing when element dropped from bag "A" with specified model  in to bag "B" without model. You need to specify the "dragulaModel" for bag "B" in which you trying to drop the element.

Example:

```html
<div [dragula]='"bag-a"' [dragulaModel]='records' >
...
</div>

<div [dragula]='"bag-b"' [dragulaModel]='records' >
..
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how this would work across two different components?